# What does Regex Index Reference Mean When Referring to Single Quotes

Tags: unicode, char

I was playing around with inputting regex patterns in https://regex101.com/
Beginning with the most simple of examples (see screenshot image below) I don't understand the explanation for my pattern `'.'` (all characters except line terminators) I am assuming that the index values provided are referencing number base terminology. That is 39 base 10, 27 base 16 & 47 base 8?

If I am correct then what is this indexing telling me?

I understand start indexes as used in the following: [MathWorks regexp](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btn_p45_sep_shared-startIndex) But this particular example, I have posted here, has regex101 referencing the single quote itself.

Perhaps my question is a little esoteric but I would appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: It's just trying to describe the character being matched in every possible way: showing the character and also its character code in various bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote char `'`, the ASCII code representation's are either:
*39* is decimal,
*27* is hex,
*47* is octal

Comment: Thanks. It seems obvious now that you have pointed it out :-/